# Why Jest is executing code that is not in the scope?

Tags: redux, jestjs

While writing a test for middleware:

```js
export const myMiddleware = ({getState, dispatch}) => next => action => {

  console.log("action.type:", action.type) // 'NOTHING'
  console.log("action.type compare:", action.type=== 'targetedAction') // this is false
  
  next(action)

  if(action.type === 'targetedAction') {
  
    console.log("in if:" )
    const state = getState()

    const data = getData(state)

    data.forEach( => { /*do something */ }) )

  }

}
```

The Jest code is :

```js
it('should pass the intercepted action to next', () => {

  const fakeNext = {fakeMethod(){return true}};
  const spy = jest.spyOn(fakeNext,'fakeMethod');
  const fakeStore = {
    dispatch: {},
    getState: jest.fn()
  };

  const action = { type: 'NOTHING' };
 
  myMiddleware(fakeStore)(spy)(action);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(action)
  
});
```

When I tried to run the test, it tries to execute the code which is inside the if condition and throws error. As my test is only about to make sure that next(action) has been executed and the action.type is not as expected, shouldn't it bypass the if condition and pass the test?

Currently, it throws error while executing getData(state).

Comment: Are you sure it's failing on `getData`? I'd expect it to fail because your `spy` doesn't match how it's using `next`.

Comment: yes, it works if I update the line ```const data = getData(state)``` as ```const data = []```.